# Selective Infinite Loop in Making a Tournament Tree

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates, infinite-loop, swap

I want to write a program that randomly generates a tournament tree using only the number of challengers. I read into another such problem, but the answer described how ranks would take part and seeding the players, which went a little over head.

The problem I am facing is that my algorithm produces an infinite loop for values between 1 and 4 inclusively. For all values otherwise, the program runs as desired.

My approach was to take in an array of strings for the competitors' names. Then, I would iterate over each position and randomly select a competitor's name to take that spot. Because I am swapping the names, I have to check for duplicates in the array. I believe this is where my code is experiencing issues.

Here is the snippet that actually determines the tree

```
for(int i = 0; i < no_players;) {
    int index = rand() % ((no_players - i) + i);

    // randomly choose an element from the remainder
    string temp = players[index]; 
    bool unique = true;

    // check all the elements before the current position
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        // if the element is already there, it is not unique
        if(players[j] == temp)
            unique = false;
    }

    // only if the element is unique, perform the swap
    if(unique) {
        players[index] = players[i];
        players[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered debug output as the loop runs, so you can see what it's doing on each iteration?  Or merely stepping through it in the debugger line by line and examining the variables, to see if it is doing what you think it is?

Comment: Please write a ?. all you need is shift and / together it is not that hard. =(                                     https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HostileFork I tried tracing it myself, but haven't ran it through a debugger. I actually write in gedit and compile using g++. What effects might this have on the code? Because it works properly for all values greater than 4.

Comment: @lux You mean what effects will writing in gedit and compiling using g++ with no debugger have?  It will have the effect of you not being able to get a handle on your code and probably getting yelled at by people on StackOverflow to put more effort in yourself before asking.  :-)  If you want to use an open source tool on Linux that's a pretty good integrated IDE for C++, I'd suggest checking out [Qt Creator](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/).  You should be able to set breakpoints, single step, step into...etc.  Then you can watch it go through the infinite loop.

Comment: Also in the *"nickel's worth of free advice"* department: if you've isolated a case that isn't working, then focus upon that.  Telling people *"it works for cases Y and Z"* isn't compelling, because you're here to find out why it's not working in case X.  If you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that forces the non-working case to happen (preloading the data with the minimal to cause the problem, with no I/O unless the problem is with I/O), that is ideal.

Comment: @HostileFork alright, appreciate the feedback! I'll definitely work on it.